# submit don't work when have more than 3 <video> html tag

Tags: javascript, html

I've made a little game with a very basic JS knowledge its about listen to music randomly in a clip  and try to  guess what it is , i've made a random function work us a parametre for a switch case ,

```
 switch (result) {


     case 0:
        var sample = document.getElementById("leggere0");
        $("#leggere0").show(); 
        $("#leggere0").hide(4000); 
        sample.play();
        break;                                                        }
```

and after user submit it play the small clip  , 
locally all thing work fine , but after I put it online , some user when they try to play it stay sticked and can't even make log-in all submit button don't work any more,

I figure out the probleme its cause i put a 20 video html tag , when i decrease and delting some all things work properly ,

```
<video id="music1" src="playlist/leggere0.mp4"> </video>
```

I try to put the code in head or body etc and every time the same probleme

Comment: If it works locally but not online, then that probably means "playlist/leggere0.mp4" is pointing to an mp3 file on your computer but you didn't upload it to the right location

Comment: even localy its .mp4

Comment: oops i meant to say mp4 not mp3

Comment: Well, if your submit button has javascript code, and you are running into a javascript error before the submit button is clicked, it likely won't work.  Is that the case?

Comment: nope there is not error when click on submit its still loading then nothing happen , its not probleme of the mp4 format you think ?

Comment: Is there any error log being shown in console?

Comment: no there isn't error it just still loading and nothing happen